# mysql - dynamic select row as column

Tags: mysql, sql, view, dynamic-sql

Update: I want to use dynamic sql to select question as column and put answer in row, like cursor or loop, is that possible?

I want the select result like this

```
+--------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userid | Living Status | This is another question get from row and it's longer than 64 characters |
+--------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     19 | married       | q2_opt3                                                                  |
+--------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And here is my query

```
select 
       userid,
        min(if(question.ordering=1,o.name,NULL )) as 'Living Status',
        min(if(question.ordering=2,o.name,NULL )) as 'This is another question get from row and it's longer than 64 characters'
from answer
       inner join question on question.key_value = answer.key_value
       inner join q_option o on question.id = o.question_id and o.value = answer.answer
where userid in (19)
GROUP BY id
```

The question table is like

```
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| id | ordering |                                 question                                  |  key_value   |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|  1 |        1 | Living Status                                                             | livingStatus |
|  2 |        2 | This is another question get from row and it's longer than 64 characters  | question_2   |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

The answer table is like

```
+----+--------+--------------+--------+
| id | answer |  key_value   | userid |
+----+--------+--------------+--------+
|  1 |      2 | livingStatus |     19 |
|  2 |      3 | question_2   |     19 |
+----+--------+--------------+--------+
```

The q_option table is like

```
+----+----------+-------------+-------+
| id |   name   | question_id | value |
+----+----------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | single   |           1 |     1 |
|  2 | married  |           1 |     2 |
|  3 | divorced |           1 |     3 |
|  4 | q2_opt1  |           2 |     1 |
|  5 | q2_opt2  |           2 |     2 |
|  6 | q2_opt3  |           2 |     3 |
+----+----------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Well, i don't think that you can extend the maximum column length. It's fixed to maximum 64 characters!

Comment: Some solutions use CAST, but the situation is different from mine. Is there any other way like using @parameter or cursor to run throw all question list?